# Clearing up concepts for chain rule connected with rate of change

Tags: calculus

The radius of a circle increases at a rate of 3cm/s. Find the rate of increase of the area when the radius is 5cm .

my try -

$$\frac{dr}{dt} = 3cm $$

$$\frac{da}{dt} = \frac{da}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$$

Finding $\frac{da}{dr}$
$\frac{da}{dt} = \frac d{dr} (\pi r^2) = 2 \pi r $

I'm a little shocked and unsure by how it become $2 \pi r$ from $\frac d{dr} (\pi r^2)$ as it doesn't follow the rules of differentiation.

Comment: $\pi$ is a constant, so $$\frac{d}{dr} \pi r^{2} = \pi \cdot \frac{d}{dr} r^{2} = \pi \cdot 2r = 2 \pi r$$

Answer (score 2):

The general formula is:
$$\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(c.f(r)\right)=c\cdot\dfrac{d}{dr}f(r)$$
where $c$ is any constant. Here you can take $c=\pi$, and $f(r)=r^2$.

Or, you can apply:
$$\dfrac{d}{dr}\left[f(r)\cdot g(r)\right]=f(r)\cdot\dfrac{d}{dr}g(r)+g(r)\cdot\dfrac{d}{dr}f(r)$$
In this case you take $f(r)=\pi$, and $g(r)=r^2$.

Both cases produces the same result i.e $\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\pi r^2\right)=2\pi r$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dr} \left( \pi r^2 \right) = 2\pi r$$

This is perfectly fine. Remember that $\pi$ is not a variable, but a constant value (just like 2).

The differentiation rule

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( ax^b \right) = bax^{b-1}$$

applies to your equation by $a=\pi$ and $b = 2$.

Comment: But since pi is a constant . Shouldn't pi be 0 which leads to = 2r ?

Comment: @user307640 $\pi$ is 3.14159 blah blah blah and so on randomly-ish. It is not 0.